# django dev server unread POST data will error

Tags: python, django

I have the solution, this is more of a Why question.  The problem is when running a django dev server, when i make an ajax POST request with data, if the view never looks at the POST dict, i get a urllib2 exception.  "a connection was forcibly closed by a remote host" or something.

If theres no post data, it returns fine, if the data is read, not even stored, a simple

request.POST

will return ok as well.  Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code and stack trace

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're not sending the csrfmiddleware_token on your post request. It's a prevention mechanism for CSRF attacks and needs to be set on all POST messages. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable CSRF protection for that view function as it is enabled by default (the CSRF Middleware).

You can opt to disable CSRF protection via two ways:

1. Remove the CSRF middleware and use the `@csrf_protect` decorator on
   view functions that you wish to use the CSRF protection. Use this if you generally don't
   need CSRF (eg. no forms for most of the pages). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#the-decorator-method
2. Use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on the view you wish to exempt the CSRF protection from.
   This is useful when you only have a few view functions that does not require CSRF 
   protection. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions

Comment: csrf middleware isnt installed.  And wouldnt this just return a 403 if it was missing or incorrect?  Through nginx i get a 502 Bad Gateway and just hitting the django server i get a urllib2 exception.  With post data = "" it works, with data = "a=a" it will fail.

Comment: Brett, adding a stack trace back in your question will help us understand your problem better (based on your description we generally assume it is just the CSRF issue).